# How to write Cyrillic text when using the debugging format?

Tags: rust, cyrillic

While using `println!` works as expected:

```rust
println!("Привет!"); // Привет!
```

With debugging format however:

```rust
println!("{:?}", "Привет!"); // "\u{41f}\u{440}\u{438}\u{432}\u{435}\u{442}!"
```

Using `assert!`:

```rust
assert!("Привет!" != "Привет!") // 'assertion failed: "\u{41f}\u{440}\u{438}\u{432}\u{435}\u{442}!" != "\u{41f}\u{440}\u{438}\u{432}\u{435}\u{442}!"
```

Is there any way to have `assert!` print correctly in debug format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far as Rust is concerned, it *is* correct.  The implementation of `Debug` for `str` restricts itself to printable ASCII characters so that the output is readable irrespective of codepage or output mechanism.

I don't believe there's anything you can do to change this for strings *in general*; on a case-by-case basis, you can use `Display` instead, or create a wrapper around `&str` that forwards to `Display` instead of `Debug`.